# Different class loaders jsapar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, jsapar

I am currently using kafka consumer to call method which which produces a flat file using the jsapar library. On Unit tests every works fine but when using the kafka consumer jsapar is not able to get the line class.

```
BeanPropertyMap var2 = (BeanPropertyMap)this.beanPropertyMap.get(var1);
```

The beanmap has the var1 class but with different classloader hence this returns null.
I am using spring boot. Any idea about the issue.

Comment: This might be related to this issue with class loaders: https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar/issues/14
Please check if the issue has been solved in jsapar version 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by removing spring dev tools dependency. Apparently it this dependency includes a class loader. I read online that this can be disabled with the following in your application.properties spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false